# Java Generator for Poisson and Uniform Distributions?

Tags: java, distribution, generator, random, poisson

From what I understand, the standard generator is for the Normal Distribution. I have to generate random numbers according to the Normal, Uniform and Poisson Distributions, but I can't seem to find a class for the last 2.

I have to generate them in the range of 0 - 999999.

Answer (score 12):

As David has pointed out, the supplied pseudo-random number generator uses the Uniform distribution.

For the other two, I would use the [Cern Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/)  library functions:

- [Poisson](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Poisson.html)
- [Normal/Gaussian](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Normal.html)

These library functions easily allow you to find a random number taken from each distribution, rather than giving you a probability density function or cumulative density function and expecting you to derive the number yourself (which seems to be the Apache Commons-Math approach):

```
RandomEngine engine = new DRand();
Poisson poisson = new Poisson(lambda, engine);
int poissonObs = poisson.nextInt();

Normal normal = new Normal(mean, variance, engine);
double normalObs = normal.nextDouble();
```

Also, bear in mind that the Poisson distribution P(λ) for large λ can be approximated very well by the normal distribution N(λ, sqrt(λ)).

Comment: Is there a way to specify the min and max value they use? Doesn't seem like it, from what I saw.

Comment: That's because Poisson and Normal distributions don't have a maximum or minimum (well, Poisson has a fixed minimum of 0).

Comment: Two of your links are now 404.  :-(

Answer (score 6):

The standard Java RNG ([java.util.Random](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)), and its subclasses such as [java.security.SecureRandom](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), already generate uniformly distributed values.

They also have a method, [nextGaussian](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()), that returns normally-distributed values.  By default, the distribution has mean of zero and standard deviation of 1 but this is trivially tweaked.  Just multiply by the required s.d. and add the required mean.  So, for example, if you wanted normally-distributed values with a mean of 6 and standard deviation of 2.5, you'd do this:

```
double value = rng.nextGaussian() * 2.5 + 6;
```

The Poisson distribution is not explicitly supported, but you can fake it by doing the same as [Tom's Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750325/java-generator-for-poisson-and-uniform-distributions/750380#750380).

Alternatively, you may be interested in my [Uncommons Maths library](http://maths.uncommons.org), which provides utility classes for Normal, Poisson and other distributions.

Comment: The link to Uncommons is 404.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the [standard generator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) is for the uniform distribution. The basic random number generator in any language/library will always (in all cases I know of) use the uniform distribution because that's what comes out of all the popular pseudorandom number generator algorithms - basically, uniform random numbers are the easiest.

I see Eddie already pointed you to a link for other distributions so I'll skip writing the rest of this...

Comment: Actually, it looks like that link also points out the "nextGaussian" method to create normal variates too.

Answer (score 4):

Let me preface all this by the fact that none of this is truly random, I am talking about pseudo random number generators.

Let me also say that I have never had to do this for production quality code. I have done this for a hw assignment though, in Python. I simulated Poisson random variables.

The way that I did it made use of the following facts:

1. A Poisson random variable is a sum of exponential random variables.
2. We can use the inverse transform method to generate exponential random variables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling.

In particular, you can use the fact that: if X<sub>1</sub>, ..., X<sub>n</sub> are independent *standard* exponential random variables, then Z = min(k : X<sub>1</sub> + ... + X<sub>k</sub> < λ) - 1 is Poisson(λ).

So, with that, I wrote the following code in python to generate Poisson values:

```
class Poisson:
    """Generate Poisson(lambda) values by using exponential
    random variables."""

    def __init__(self, lam):
        self.__lam = lam

    def nextPoisson(self):
        sum = 0
        n = -1
        while sum < self.__lam:
            n += 1
            sum -= math.log(random.random())
        return n
```

Example usage of the class is:

```
# Generates a random value that is Poisson(lambda = 5) distributed
poisson = Poisson(5)
poisson_value = poisson.nextPoisson
```

I posted this here because it is good to know that these kinds of relationships exist, and this inverse transform method gives you a general way to deal with generating random values following a particular continuous distribution.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the numbered list to what I believe you intended.  If this is not what you intended, then of course feel free to roll back the change.