# Java generate random numbers using Possion/Gaussian/Exponential/Geometric/Uniform distribution

Tags: java, random, distribution, gaussian, exponential

How can I generate a random number in Java using different distributions within a range(0-99).

I know the standard Java.util.Random getNextInt() uses Uniform and PRNG. How would I use nextGaussian?
But how would I generate the rest?
The problem is that they need to be within a specified range(0-99), and the Random lib doesn't have
nextPossion, nextExponential, nextGeometric etc?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750325/java-generator-for-poisson-and-uniform-distributions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [uncommons maths library](http://maths.uncommons.org/) has a bunch of tools for generating numbers from various distributions. From the website: "can be used to generate values from Uniform, Normal, Binomial, Poisson and Exponential distributions."

It also has implementations of `Random` that are significantly better (for various flavours of "better") than what ships with the JDK.