# Is there a Java probability library somewhere?

Tags: java, random, probability

One that would, for example, allow me to create a Poisson random variable with specified lambda and generate random numbers with it, or to calculate the marginals from a discrete  joint probability distribution function?

Or should I roll my own? (This is just for fun, I just want to play around with probability a bit, so no practical uses yet :) )

Comment: this is what a search engine is for..

Comment: @mre that isn't constructive. The idea is for SO to *become* the answer you find on a search engine.....

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740602/recommended-java-maths-stats-library

Comment: @mikera, yeah..my bad..been on this site all day..need to step away from the machine now..

Comment: @mikera Except for answers which can already be found with a search engine. That's why we ask people to do research first. In this case, you can actually find the answer to this question *on stackoverflow* with a google search.

Comment: @mre I already tried a Google search which didn't turn up anything useful for me

Comment: @mre and what would that Stackoverflow answer be? I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: @wrongusername A search for *probability library java* gives `jprobdist` as the second result - "a Java library for probability and statistics`. If it's specifically Poisson values you're looking for, then a google search for *poisson value java* gives [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750325/java-generator-for-poisson-and-uniform-distributions)

Comment: @Telthien ahh thanks! I wasn't looking for Poisson random variables specifically, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Guava also has a math library that you can check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) has a class called [PoissonDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/PoissonDistribution.html), from which you can sample random values with `sample()`

Also, if you want to play around with probability, you should check out [R](http://www.r-project.org/), a language custom-built for probability programming (that also seems to have a [pretty vibrant SO presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r))